# Using methods of my runnable class in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Lets say I have class called Foo looking smth like this:

```
class Foo implements Runnable {
   String hello = "hello!"

   @Override
   public void run() {
    //infinite loop doing smth...
   }

   public void sayHello() {
     System.out.println(hello);
   }
}
```

And I want to create and start thread in my main class.

```
//code..
Runnable run = new Foo();
Thread th = new Thread(run);
th.start();
//code..
```

Thread has infinite loop so it is working all the time. Is it possible to call 'sayHello' method from main class?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look into _separation of concerns_.

Comment: What do you think will happen if you call sayHello() from your main()? This question could be answered very easily just by typing the code into an editor and running it. It's really not a quality question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Foo run = new Foo();//change to Foo
Thread th = new Thread(run);
th.start();
//invoke 
run.sayHello();
```

Try to change Runnable to Foo then you can use the method from that Foo class